# «Борода клинушком» — тип связи

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, словосочетания

Какой тип подчинительной связи наблюдается в словосочетании *борода клинушком*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это именно примыкание.

§ 1834. К беспредложному присубстантивному примыканию относится примыкание им., род. и тв. падежей.
*1) Примыкание таких существительных, которые имеют формоизменение, однако в определяющей функции при том или другом имени ведут себя как неизменяемые слова:* **программа максимум, программа минимум, плюс - минус единица (эффект равен минус единице), стиль брасс, баттерфляй (плыть брассом, но стилем брасс).** **Такие сочетания практически не входят в отношения вариативной связи ни с какими другими сочетаниями.**
 2) Примыкание тв. п. к существительным конкретных значений, обычно определяемых со стороны внешних признаков или свойств, качеств: **платье цветочками, сапоги раструбами, галстук шнурочком, город террасами; привез ему записку карандашом из штаба (Булг.);** *Это был совершенно ужасный этюд масляными красками (Симон.). Определение при этом часто осуществляется через сравнение:* **усы кисточкой, колечком, щеточкой, кепка блином, борода лопатой, сапоги бутылками, голова тыквой, каблуки рюмочкой, лес стеной.**

Источник: Аг-80

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на АГ–80. Такие сочетания можно считать и слабоуправляемыми, хотя действительно примыкание в них более очевидно.

Comment: Вы правы,  такие сочетания считаются слабоуправляемыми.

Comment: А вот и ваш пример. Приложение, определяющее существительное через сравнение, уподобление, может варьироваться с тв. п. с тем же значением: усы-щеточка - усы щеточкой, шляпа-пирожок - пирожком, голова-тыква - тыквой, ***борода-клинушек - клинушком***, брови-серпики - серпиками.

Answer (score 4):

[**клинышком**](https://all_words.acahttps://all_words.academic.ru/32822/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BCdemic.ru/32822/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC), ***в значении наречия***

1. Наподобие, в виде небольшого вытянутого треугольника.
   Участок клинышком подходил к лесу.
2. **Лекс., *в функции определения*.**
   Бородка клинышком. Чёлка клинышком.

В большом толковом словаре:
КЛИНЫШКОМ
нареч. качеств.-обстоят., разг., ласк. к нареч. *клином*.

Главное слово [бородка] не способно диктовать зависимому [клинушком] свою форму, потому что зависимое не изменяется: бородой (какой?) клинушком, бороду (какую?) клинушком.
Думаю, что это примыкание.
[Типы подчинительных связей](https://5-ege.ru/tipy-podchinitelnoj-svyazi-v-slovosoch/)

*А сам — в чем только душа — худенький, хиленький, сивая борода клинушком, седые кудри рассыпались по лбу и вискам (Е. Н. Опочинин).*

*Но самое видное место здесь занимает хозяин дома — плотный, среднего роста человек с широкой, выпуклой спиной, с мягким, немного расплывчатым лицом, окаймленным седой бородой клинушком и густыми серыми усами* (А. И. Свирский).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Всё бы хорошо, но примыкание подразумевает неизменяемые формы слов. Тут есть еще одна возможность, которая формально на настоящем этапе развития языка была бы чуть более подходящей в нашем случае. Посмотрим, может кто о ней напишет.

Comment: Я ориентировалась на стандартную формулировку (примыкание — вид подчинительной связи, при которой неизменяемое зависимое слово присоединяется к главному только по смыслу) и распространенные примеры (пальто нараспашку, взгляд исподлобья)

Answer (score 2):

**Именное примыкание.**
Такой вид связи  квалифицируется по-разному: ползти змеей, стричься ежиком, так как существительное с предлогом по своему значению близко к наречию, хотя и не стало им.

В таких словосочетаниях способ связи определяется **то как слабое управление, то как примыкание.** Поэтому некоторые исследователи называют такой способ связи **именным примыканием.** При именном примыкании главным оказывается не предметное значение примыкающего имени, а атрибутивное и падежная форма.